# Python : Keeping up the number of points in a live plot

Tags: python, file, matplotlib

I have been trying to create a live plot by matplotlib.

My trial code is this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import time
from PySide import QtCore

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

N=100

def animate(j):
    graph_data = open('example.txt','r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs=[]
    ys=[]

    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x,y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(float(x))
            ys.append(float(y))
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs, ys)

def initFile():
    fid = open('example.txt','w')
    fid.write('')
    fid.close()
    for i in range(0,N):
        fid = open('example.txt', 'a')
        fid.write(str(i) + ',' + str(0) + '\n')
        fid.close()


def updateFile():
    global wThread
    wThread = writeThread()
    wThread.start()


class writeThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.exiting = False

    def run(self):
        i=0
        while 1:
            fid = open('example.txt', 'a')
            fid.write(str(N+i) + ',' + str(np.sin(2*np.pi*0.05*i)) + '\n')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            i=i+1
            fid.close()

initFile()
updateFile()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 200)
plt.show()
```

It works well. But, the plot points are accumulated. I want to keep up the number of points in my plot as `N`.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply restrict the size of your array/list to the last N points:

```
def animate(j):
    (...)
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs[-N:], ys[-N:])
```

Comment: That's one way. But I want to update the data file as N lines.